# Set up a webserver for multiple users and makes PHP scripts run under their account (with their permissions)

Tags: apache2, web-hosting, shared-hosting, suphp

I'm setting up an Apache 2.2 webserver for multiple users (having the "developers" profile).
They need to execute PHP scripts/applications (both home-made and acquired) and run

I tried using *mod_userdir* but the problem is that Apache (thus the scripts) runs under "www-data" (I'm using GNU/Debian OS).

So I looked at suPHP but it doesn't support *php_admin_value* Apache directives.

I also saw apache2-mpm-itk mentioned but it uses virtual hosts, which itself requires DNS.
I think I could see some workaround to that if I was to install a DNS server on the webserver managing a subdomain via delegation (eg. my webserver's FQDN is "*testsrv.mycompany.tld*" and users's virtual host's FQDN would be "*user1.testsrv.mycompany.tld*", "*user2.testsrv.mycompany.tld*"). But it might a bit "too much" no?

Answer (score 0):

You could use virtual hosts along with [mod_auth_basic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) so `user1` would have a password protected site at `www.user1.example.com`.

If by 'php_admin_value' you are refering to the .htaccess files, then yes they are not supported by suPHP but I believe there is a way around that.

Finally, I am setting up my server locally (for testing) so I just updated my `/etc/hosts/` file. That might be a good place for you to start.